# How Can I implement DreamFactory Services Platform for my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7

Did any one use DreamFactory Services Platform for your iphone app?. How can I implement it on iphone apps ?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as an "opinion" question.  You need to ask *concrete* programming questions and not opinion questions. [According to DreamFactory's developer's FAQ](https://www.dreamfactory.com/developers/faq), they do support iOS.

Comment: Yes, we have an iOS native library and sample app. Check out our site for links. http://www.dreamfactory.com/. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

DreamFactory uses the Swagger REST API spec.  There is a repo which has a static library you can import to make all the calls to any service on your DSP at https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/ios-sdk.  A sample app should be available by Monday.